# Travis CI config for setting the .env file

Tags: environment-variables, travis-ci

I am creating a new build for two environments, test.site.com and qa.site.com. Each build copies either `.env.test` or `.env.qa` to the root dir.

Is there a more efficient way of creating the two builds since the only difference is which .env file is copied or is this the right way?

**.travis.yml**

```
dist: trusty
sudo: false
language: php
php: 7.1

env:
- BUILD_ENV=test
- BUILD_ENV=qa

install:
- composer install --no-interaction

before_script:
- cp envs/.env.${BUILD_ENV} .env
```

Comment: Cant you take the outcome of the first build job copy it and replace only the config in the other site working directory?

Comment: Looks like a working way, and it is pretty self-explanatory. Maybe would even call it the right way.